Horror/thriller movie about a parent haunted by their child's spirit after a car accident, culminating in a time-travel effort to prevent the accident
I haven’t seen this movie since I was young, and honestly, some of the moments I remember, I could have mistaken. But it doesn’t hurt to try.
I believe it was a thriller or horror movie, and what happens is there is a family of about three. One day, one of the parents decides to take their daughter to a game or the movies, but one of the parents decides not to go, and the family ends up dying in a car accident.
The parent left behind is haunted by the loss of their family and constantly feels the spirit of the child. There’s one scene where they actually bust down a wall, and the child was in the wall.
In the end, I believe somehow they went back in time, and the parent prevented them from going to where their death awaited them.

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could it be "The Changeling" (1980), "Don't Look Now" (1973), or "Premonition" (2007)?
